# How can I make compiled react file smaller?

Tags: reactjs

I started writing a new app in React and I copy - pasted my gulp configuration from a previous project. I don't remember how I created this gulp configuration, so please help me with understanding what is in there.

The problem is that my compiled React app is very big. It's almost 2MB in size, all of this with nothing but "var React = require('react');" in my main file.

This is the gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var es6ify = require('es6ify');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var tap        = require("gulp-tap");
var gutil      = require('gulp-util');
var babelify = require('babelify');


//script to not need to require
/*var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
 pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', 'main-bower-files'],
 replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});*/

var dest = 'src/'; 

function handleError(err) {
  console.log(err.toString());
  this.emit('end');
}
 

gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'renderjs'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        browser: "chrome",
        server: "./app",
        port: 3000
        
    });

    gulp.watch("src/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("app/**/*.php").on('change', browserSync.reload); 
    gulp.watch("assets/**/*").on("change", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("src/react/**/*.js", ['renderjs']);  
     gulp.watch("src/react/**/*.jsx", ['renderjs']);  
     
});



// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});



 

var dest = "assets/";

function build2(){
    return gulp.src("src/react/main.js")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(tap(
        function(file)
        {
            var d = require('domain').create();
            d.on("error",
                function(err){
                    gutil.log(gutil.colors.red("Browserify compile error:"), err.message, "\n\t", gutil.colors.cyan("in file"), file.path);
                      gutil.beep();
                }
            );
            
            d.run(function(){
               file.contents = browserify({
                   entries: [file.path],
                   transform: [babelify.configure({
                       presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                       plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']
                   })],
                   debug: true
               }).bundle();
            });
        }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
};

gulp.task('renderjs', build2);


gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Most guys on the web tell me to edit my Webpack configuration, but I'm pretty sure Webpack is not used for this configuration.

My package.json looks like this:

```js
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "0.0.1", 
  "description": "A web app for ...",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.5",
    "flux": "^3.1.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.13.1", 
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-form-data": "^0.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-require": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.6",
    "browserify": "^13.3.0",
    "domain": "0.0.1",
    "es6ify": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-reactify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-tap": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "jest": "^18.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-transform": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0",
    "webpack-module-hot-accept": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/eightmd/SUN-Calculator.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/MikeMrk/crud#readme"
}
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your minify/uglify?

Comment: Also make you sure you distinguish correctly between dependencies and dev dependencies. Why is gulp in your dependencies?